# Is it possible to upload two nearly identical apps under different names?

Tags: android, google-play

I am planning to run an A/B test for a few weeks before publishing the final (one) app.

The problem is, simply sending my 30 testers .apk files and have them activate "allow installation from unknown sources" will look shady to them. I'd like for it to look official.

The difference in the apps is basically just a different sqlite file.

I am worried that Google might just take it down without warning and hurt my testing schedule.

Comment: Why don't you use playstore's beta testing feature?

Comment: @Abbas Didn't know that, thanks! But is it possible to test two apps simultaneously like I described? I would simply create two apps and let each run as a beta test, right?

Comment: If the difference between both apps is just the database file, then you should probably write your app in such a way that it handles both cases. However if the two apps are completely different then you should create a new application and start a beta there.